# Mysql multi-table UPDATE first record

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have a permission system between two objects (users => firms) with table `permissions` for linking. Now i need to update `firms` table with first permission user id. I made this query:

```
UPDATE parim_firms, parim_permissions
SET parim_firms.firm_user_id = parim_permissions.permission_a_id
WHERE parim_firms.firm_user_id = 0
    AND parim_firms.firm_id = parim_permissions.permission_b_id
```

Now if *one firm hash multiple linked users*, then will it be updated with the first or last matched user?

My logic says after first update `firm_user_id != 0` and that row doesn't get updated anymore.

But im not sure, maybe does it run the query for all joined rows and the last row will stay.

And if it doesn't then how can i modify the query to update with only **first** matched result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 UPDATE parim_firms 
 SET parim_firms.firm_user_id = 
  ( 
    select  parim_permissions.permission_a_id from parim_permissions 
    WHERE   parim_firms.firm_id = 0 
    AND parim_firms.firm_id = parim_permissions.permission_b_id 
 )
```

or

```
update parim_firms  a
set a.firm_user_id  = b.permission_a_id 
from  parim_permissions  b
WHERE   parim_firms.firm_id = 0 
    AND parim_firms.firm_id = parim_permissions.permission_b_id
```